# How to keep extruded edges connected to the rest of the mesh?

Tags: modeling

I open blenders default scene and select the edge of a cube.  I can now grab it around so it stays part of the mesh

[image: I open blenders default scene and select the edge of a cube. I can now grab it around so it stays part of the mesh]

Now when I hit extrude and right click to cancel it, whenever I try to move my edge it will not stay attached to the mesh like in fig1

[image: Now when I hit extrude and right click to cancel it, whenever I try to move my edge it will not stay attached to the mesh like in fig1]

How to I get an edge, or any piece of geometry back to where you can grab it around and the rest of the mesh stays connected like in fig 1?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you clarify more?

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific.   When I grab an edge I can move it around so it stays connected  with the mesh like in the first pic.  When I extrude he edge and right click, then try to grab the edge,  the edge wont stay connected to the mesh.  Like in fig 2

Comment: You might best be suited to see a video tutorial series for beginners.   This site is not directed to tutorials. Here is one.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY6KPrc4uMw&list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS . Please consider switching selection mode to face or edge or vertex.  Determine if you want to extrude or [not] extrude.  Grabbing and extruding are different.  Someone else may present a fuller answer to you.

Comment: Could you better explain what the problem is? What aren't you able to do?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I created a cube, went into edit mode, selected two vertices (an edge), extruded them, right-clicked and grabbed them again with "G". They were still connected to the cube. Even after deselecting and reselecting them. Can you retry it in a completely new blender file? If the problem still appears, please describe your actions step by step. Greets
Jaspa

Comment: That's what extrude is supposed to do... it extrudes the selected vertices. when you move the extruded vertices it doesn't move the rest of the mesh.

Comment: When you extrude, right click does not cancel the extrusion, but it cancels the movement consecutive to the extrusion. So if you right click, the extruded part comes back to the location of the original extruded edge. That means you now have 2 edges at the exact same position. To cancel it totally, hit Ctrl+Z, just after : E then right click then Ctrl + Z

Answer (score 1):

Hit <kbd>X</kbd> > <kbd>Vertices</kbd>, then select the original edge.

Answer (score 1):

What you did initially was you have extruded the edge, but by hitting <kbd>Right Click</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> (letting go), the extruded edge has been created but is now resting over the original edge.

The solution to this is to select your mesh in *Object Mode* then hit  <kbd>tab</kbd>to go into *Edit Mode* then hit  <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, and t <kbd>M</kbd> *Merge > By Distance* .

This deleted the extra vertex that were sitting over eachother on the exact same location in 3D space. You will see pop up at the bottom saying "Removed this many vertices".